# How to convert oddly partioned dynamic disk to basic without formatting it?

Tags: windows, partitioning, dynamic-disk

I am currently planning to switching to Debian and wanted to access my storage drive as I keep most of my games and work on there. However it wouldn't mount and I checked the drive.

All was well apart from the odd partition style, which rules out the DiskPart method as I've expanded the drives as far as I can remember.

Edit: Without losing data, preferably.
[image: Image of Disk Management.]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk

Comment: `The disk must not contain any volumes or data before you can change it back to a basic disk.` I said in the title without losing data.

Comment: Microsoft does not support any other method. There are third-party software market as being able to do that. You can find it easily by googling. How reliable they are I can't say. It's up to you.